# how to remove event of object created from control collection

Tags: vb.net

I have the follwing error message

> 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)

when trying the following code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xbutton As Control

    For Each xbutton In gcFRightMenu.Controls
        If xbutton.Name = commandbutton(0) Then

            RemoveHandler xbutton.MouseDown, AddressOf xbutton.MouseDown

            AddHandler xbutton.MouseDown, AddressOf _MouseDown

        End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub _MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, 
                       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then SendKeys.Send("{ESC}")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove event

```
RemoveHandler xbutton.MouseDown, AddressOf xbutton.MouseDown
```

`AddressOf`expecting for a name of the method, but `xbutton.MouseDown` is name of an event.

If you want to be sure that eventhandler `_MouseDown` added only ones to the control, then remove it always before adding

```
For Each xbutton In gcFRightMenu.Controls
    If xbutton.Name = commandbutton(0) Then

        RemoveHandler xbutton.MouseDown, AddressOf _MouseDown

        AddHandler xbutton.MouseDown, AddressOf _MouseDown

    End If
Next
```